# Interfacing the 1366x768 HDMI display on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have HDMI display which has corrupted EDID checksum and its working with other ARM board with work around.
The same display I am using on Rpi3 & rpi zero boards and got the below output image.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13h7srCBQk_LqK2OXenCvuwivFZBHoO_9/view

Seems its using correct 1366x768 resolution but color is not correct, what could be the problem ?
And this is my config.txt file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ydf13vYktgfleqCeXJb2SZX6PsErL1dq/view

Here is the link where I discussed the issue. BTW, this HDMI diplay works with Windows & Linux PC without any issues.

https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/19407/change-hdmi-lcd-resolution-in-toradex-imx6-board.html

Patches:

https://share.toradex.com/lg644qhtqv1jnk9?direct

https://share.toradex.com/pyzdaan5ozk9v4k?direct

How the EDID is handled in rpi hdmi driver if any corrupted or incorrect EDID data present ?
Thanks for the support & help.

Answer (score 1):

The below forum link solved the problem. Hope it would help someone.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=205958&p=1277210#p1277210